# Signal with cfn-signal in nested stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I have a nested stack which consists of 2 stacks:

- a Launchtemplate Stack and
- a Autoscaling stack

I have set a creation policy for my autoscaling group which gets notified via cfn-signal.

The cfn-signal is embedded into the User Data script in my Launchtemplate like that:

```
     UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub
        - |
            #!/bin/bash
            yum update -y
            yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --region ${AWS::Region} --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSLaunchtemplate --region ${AWS::Region} crontab /home/ec2-user/crontab
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --region ${AWS::Region} --stack ECSAutoscaling-stack --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup
            #Join the Invoiceapp ECS cluster
            echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ECSCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
        - ECSCluster:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-ECSClusterName
```

the Autoscaling stack is named: `ECSAutoscaling-stack`as written above. I will be generated after the Launchtemplate Stack exists. But somehow it doesnt work, I always get the message:

```
Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 3. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
```

so I'm  wondering where is the error? Or cant I specify the name of the ECSAutoscaling-stack like that?

Merci A

Comment: Under the `CreationPolicy` property for the Launchtemplate resource, have you set a `Timeout`? The default is 5 minutes before it wants to receive the signal(s), and that may not be enough time depending on the time it takes for everything in the UserData

Comment: merci @tkwargs I did set a timeout, but i'm not sure if the reference is sound to the ```--stack ECSAutoscaling-stack --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup```

Comment: @aerioeus are you sure the stack is named `ECSAutoscaling-stack`? Typically AWS would append a lot of letters at the end of it, so it is unlikely you would know in a static way. You will usually refer to as `${AWS::StackId}` (if you are referring to the same stack) or you need to pass the StackId of the stack you want to reference as a Input Parameter to the stack where this resource is located.